# как добавить иконку профиля

Tags: php

В чате выводятся информационные сообщения,показывается логин пользователя,нужно,чтобы слева показывалась иконка(ранг)пользователя,иконки хранятся в папке /rank,в бд есть значения `rang`,отвечающее за количество набранного опыта(нужно для повышения ранга)и `rang_id`со значениями 01,05 и тд(отвечает за номер ранга)Как сделать,чтобы слева от логина в сообщении выводилась иконка ранга?

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `chat` (`login`,`text`,`group`,`id`) VALUES('sys','Пользователь  $rank_id <font color=\"yellow\">$login</font> купил подарочную карту <font color=\"red\">$cardName</font>.','0',NULL)");
```

На странице профиля пользователя к примеру иконки выводятся,реализовано там это так:

```
<tr><td id="lef">Звание:</td><td id="rig">
                <?php if ($info['rang'] <= 10) {$limit = 10;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_01.png\">Новобранец<br>$rang/10"); $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 10 && $info['rang'] < 30) {$limit = 30;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_02.png\">Рядовой<br>$rang/50"); $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 30 && $info['rang'] < 50) {$limit = 50;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_03.png\">Ефрейтор<br>$rang/50");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 50 && $info['rang'] < 150) {$limit = 150;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_04.png\">Капрал<br>$rang/150");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 150 && $info['rang'] < 370) {$limit = 370;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_05.png\">Мастер-капрал<br>$rang/370");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 370 && $info['rang'] < 710) {$limit = 710;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_06.png\">Сержант<br>$rang/710"); $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 710 && $info['rang'] < 1230) {$limit = 1230;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_07.png\">Штаб-сержант<br>$rang/1230");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 1230 && $info['rang'] < 2000) {$limit = 2000;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_08.png\">Мастер-сержант<br>$rang/2000");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 2000 && $info['rang'] < 2900) {$limit = 2900;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_09.png\">Первый сержант<br>$rang/2900");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 2900 && $info['rang'] < 4100) {$limit = 4100;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_10.png\">Сержант-Майор<br>$rang/4100");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 4100 && $info['rang'] < 5700) {$limit = 5700;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_11.png\">Уорэнт-офицер 1<br>$rang/5700");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 5700 && $info['rang'] < 7600) {$limit = 7600;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_12.png\">Уорэнт-офицер 2<br>$rang/7600");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 7600 && $info['rang'] < 9800) {$limit = 9800;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_13.png\">Уорэнт-офицер 3<br>$rang/9800");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 9800 && $info['rang'] < 12500) {$limit = 12500;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_14.png\">Уорэнт-офицер 4<br>$rang/12500");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 12500 && $info['rang'] < 15600) {$limit = 15600;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_15.png\">Уорэнт-офицер 5<br>$rang/15600");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 15600 && $info['rang'] < 19200) {$limit = 19200;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_16.png\">Младший лейтенант<br>$rang/19200");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 19200 && $info['rang'] < 23300) {$limit = 23300;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_17.png\">Лейтенант<br>$rang/23300");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 23300 && $info['rang'] < 28000) {$limit = 28000;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_18.png\">Старший лейтенант<br>$rang/28000");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 28000 && $info['rang'] < 33200) {$limit = 33200;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_19.png\">Капитан<br>$rang/33200");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 33200 && $info['rang'] < 39000) {$limit = 3900;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_20.png\">Майор<br>$rang/39000");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 39000 && $info['rang'] < 45500) {$limit = 45500;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_21.png\">Подполковник<br>$rang/45500");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 45500 && $info['rang'] < 52700) {$limit = 52700;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_22.png\">Полковник<br>$rang/52700");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 52700 && $info['rang'] < 60600) {$limit = 60600;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_23.png\">Бригадир<br>$rang/60600");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 60600 && $info['rang'] < 69200) {$limit = 69200;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_24.png\">Генерал-майор<br>$rang/69200");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 69200 && $info['rang'] < 78700) {$limit = 78700;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_25.png\">Генерал-лейтенант<br>$rang/78700");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 78700 && $info['rang'] < 88900) {$limit = 88900;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_26.png\">Генерал<br>$rang/88900");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 88900 && $info['rang'] < 100000) {$limit = 100000;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_27.png\">Маршал<br>$rang/100000");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 100000 && $info['rang'] < 112200) {$limit = 112200;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_28.png\">Фельдмаршал<br>$rang/112200");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 112200 && $info['rang'] < 125500) {$limit = 125500;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_29.png\">Командор<br>$rang/125500");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
                <?php if ($info['rang'] > 125500){$limit = 125500;echo ("<img src=\"rank/icons_small_30.png\">Генералиссимус");  $pc = ((int)$rang / $limit) * 100; echo '<br><div class="loadbox"><div style="width:' . $pc . '%" id="level2"></div></div>'; } ?>
```

Comment: Реализовано в профиле ужасно. Надо всё переписать. Например, у вас не будет выводиться ранг вообще, если он точно соответствует граничному значению (100000, например). Но что вам мешает сделать точно, как в приведенном вами коде? Он плохой, но работает же.

Comment: вставлял тот кусок кода,не работает,если можете,напишите,как правильно вставить

Comment: Вот такой вариант еще был 



$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `chat` (`login`,`text`,`group`,`id`) VALUES('sys','Пользователь  <img onclick=\"('$user')\" src=\"rank/icons_small_$rang.png\"><font color=\"yellow\">$login</font> купил подарочную карту <font color=\"red\">$cardName</font>.','0',NULL)");

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю создать в БД отдельную таблицу рангов "ranks" со структурой

```
id ранга (id) | название ранга (rank_name) | минимальное кол-во очков (min_points) | максимальное кол-во очков (max_points) | ссылка на иконку (link_to_png)
```

И на странице профиля пользователя запрашивать его ранг `$info['rang']`, обращаясь к таблице базы данных с рангами, примерно так: `SELECT link_to_png FROM ranks WHERE min_points < {$info['rang']} AND max_points > {$info['rang']}`.
Полученную ссылку сохранить в переменную и вызвать её в шаблоне.

Comment: А в бд типа по умолчанию поставить минимум и максимум ?И какие там будут значения ?

Comment: Структуру таблицы можно сделать примерно такую: id: первичный (primary)(int(11)) || rank_name: varchar(128) || min_points: varchar(128) || max_points: varchar(128) || link_to_png: varchar(128). И далее в таблицу уже добавлять все ранги.

Comment: ну я сделал таблицу со столбцами,что дальше ?

Comment: Заполнить таблицу всеми рангами от "Новобранец" до "Генералиссимус". Выполнить запрос, результат сохранить в переменную. На странице профиля вызвать переменную с результатом запроса из этой таблицы. Смысл запроса в том, что он возвращает ссылку на иконку (link_to_png) для количества очков, которое находится между минимумом (min_points) и максимумом (max_points) для ранга (rank_name), который добавлен в таблице.

Comment: Можете,пожалуйста написать код с переменными и как в бд заполнить что и где

Comment: Добавьте все ранги в созданную Вами таблицу 'ranks'. Почитайте документацию по MySQL. Ознакомьтесь как минимум с этой функцией [ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) для того, чтобы запросить из базы данных иконку `link_to_png` для ранга. Подсказку, как сформировать запрос к базе данных, я привёл в ответе.